Adding numbers in Excel, based on a condition
What I am wanting to do is probably a straightforward issue but many, many Google searches have failed to uncover the right syntax - in Excel, I'm wanting to say something like:
'if A1 < 0, then sum columns(B1 - S1) plus A1; otherwise [ so, if A1 <=0 ], place a word instead'
At present I am trying to use a formula thus:
=IF(A1<0,(SUM(B1:S1)+A1),"credit")
So basically, a check column that should resolve to '0' for debits, and show clearly where there is a credit.
It must be possible to achieve that with a function, but I can't discover what it is - the word 'credit' appears successfully when A1 > 0, but otherwise I get nonsense.
Some version of SUMIF() perhaps, but cannot figure out its syntax. Many thanks!
Many versions of =IF() and =SUMIF() tried further to guidance I have found online - there are tens of thousands of examples of something like this but nothing that really matches.

IF is likely the way I would do it and I do not see anything obviously wrong with your formula. But if all you share is "I get nonsense" without telling us what that nonsense is, without showing the data from your sheet and without sharing the value you expect to get, I do not see how I can figure it out for you. PS: Why do you keep A1 outside the SUM. Why not do, more simply, SUM(A1:S1)? PPS: Did you mean otherwise [ so, if A1 >= 0 ] or is there a flaw in your logic?

Agree with @Atmo on all points. Provide clear examples of input and expected output.

Is the formula in A1 itself =SUM(B1:S1)?
If so, changing your formula to handle the situation where A1 is negative should ensure it either resolves to 0 or returns credit, This can be achieved by swapping the '+' with a '-', see below.
=IF(A1<0,(SUM(B1:S1) - A1),"credit")

Agree with the comments of @atmo and @Solar Mike that more information on inputs and desired outputs would be useful but this seems to be a likely oversight.

Thank you all for your help on this matter. I should have made clear that the format of the spreadsheet was a little more complicated than i was showing, and the columns I was working with were not consecutive (so not in fact, A1, B1 etc). I had it almost right, but discover that spaces around the plus or minus, determine whether it works correctly - I had no idea about this (or had forgotten)!
So the actual, correct formula is:
=IF(D5<0,(SUM(L5:T5) + D5),"credit")
